# PG::ConnectionBad Postgres Cluster down

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, postgresql-9.5

Digitalocean disabled my droplet's internet access. After fixing the error (rollback to older backup) they restored the internet access. But afterwards I constantly get an error when deploying, I can't seem to get my Postgres database up and running.

I'm getting an error each time I try to deploy my application.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So I used SSH to login to my server and check if my Postgres was actually running with:

`pg_lsclusters`

**Results into:**

`Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`

**Postgres server status**

So my Postgres server seems to be down. I tried putting it 'up' again with:

`pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main start` After doing so I got the error: `Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 403.`

And `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster` on line 403 says:

`system 'systemctl', 'is-active', '-q', "postgresql\@$version-$cluster";`
But I'm not to sure what the problem could be here and how I could fix this.

### Update

I also tried updating the permissions on `/bin` to 755 as mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=882648). Sadly that did not fix my problem.

### Update 2

I changed the /usr/bin to 755. Now when I try `pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main start`, I get this:

> Job for postgresql@9.5-main.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

And inside the `systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service`:

```
postgresql@9.5-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 17:32:38 EST; 45s ago
  Process: 22473 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 28 17:32:08 *url* systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
Jan 28 17:32:38 *url* postgresql@9.5-main[22473]: The PostgreSQL server failed to start.
Jan 28 17:32:38 *url* systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 28 17:32:38 *url* systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
Jan 28 17:32:38 *url* systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 17:32:38 *url* systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You better not mix `systemctl` and `pg_ctlcluster`. Let `systemctl` makes the calls to `pg_ctlcluster` with the right user and permissions. You should start your postgresql instance with

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service
```

Also, check the errors in the startup log. You can post them too, to help you figure out what's going on.

Your `systemctl status` also outputs that the service is disable, so, when the server reboots, you will have to start the service manually. To enable it run:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql@9.5-main.service
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly because /etc/hosts file is somehow changed.I have removed extra space inside /etc/hosts file.Use cat /etc/hosts 
Add these lines into the file

1. 127.0.0.1  localhost
2. 127.0.1.1  your-host-name
3. ::1  ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

And I have given permission 644 to /etc/hosts file.It is working for me even after the reboot of the system.